# check box gets reset of any mandatory fields is left unfilled in form submission

Tags: reset, forms

Check box gets resetted on any mandatory fields left unfilled in form submission.
I give server side validations to first name and last name fields but I am not giving any validation to check box.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form name="input" action="/saveuser" method="get">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    I have married :<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Server side validation:

```
validation.required(firstname).message("Please enter firstname");
validation.required(lastname).message(Please enter lastname);
```

Description :

It is my server side validation.Now problem is when user with out filling any  mandatory field like first name or last name and checkin the checkbox then user submit the form.Then form getting validation messages from server side but check box gets reset of any mandatory fields. But check box not gets reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution for this, get the value from server side of that select box either user selected or not then I will send that value to client side.Depending on that value I keep that select box is selected or not.But is there any other solution for this please help me.